# circular progress bar does not reset

Tags: javascript

I have a progress bar (jquery,CSS),based on a selection in dropdown list,and pressing filter button,it assigns a value to the progress bar,and starts filling the bar,min value is 0 and max is 342,the counter works ,the problem is the progress bar,for example if you give it 20,it starts filling the bar based on 20 value,but if you change the number to 50(for example),the counter starts from 0 to 50 but the filling bar starts to fill the bar from last given point(20),how should i make this bar to fill the progress bar every time from the 0 point?

here is the code:

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function () {$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      url: "@Url.Action("fault_crew","Dashbrd")",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": dtDrpVals.drpValue}),
          success: function (result) {
          var numberOfStudents = null;
          numberOfStudents= result[0].Number_Of_Students;
      //Circular chart to show number of Students
        $.fn.progresscir = function (options) {
          var circleMultiplier = (360 / options.total) || 3.6,
            progresscir = $(this),
            completed = options.completed;

          if (completed > options.total / 2) {
              progresscir.addClass('gt50');
          }
          var text = '<strong>' + completed + '</strong>';
          progresscir.find('.result-text').html(text);

          var rotationDegrees = circleMultiplier * completed;
          $('.bar', progresscir).css({
              '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + rotationDegrees + 'deg)',
              '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rotationDegrees + 'deg)',
              '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + rotationDegrees + 'deg)',
              '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + rotationDegrees + 'deg)',
              'transform': 'rotate(' + rotationDegrees + 'deg)'
          });
          };
      // end of jQuery wdget.

      // call the widget 
     function showProgress(completed, total) {
     $('#custom1').progresscir({
            completed: completed,
            total: total});}
      var start = 0,
      end = numberOfTurbines,
      total = 342,
      t;
      t = setInterval(function () {
      showProgress(start, total);
      start++;
      if (start - 1 === end) {
      clearInterval(t);
     $('.progresscir').css('background-color', 'white');

        }
        }, 0);
```

Im new in java script,but i feel it has something to do with DOM,how should i clear it from the DOM,every time before re initialize it?

Comment: I assume you have a CSS `transition` doing the actual animating. To "reset" your bar, you need to (temporarily) remove the `transition`, set the `transform` to zero, then reinstate the `transition` before setting the new value. However, note that CSS changes are "batched" together, so you will need to delay the reinstating and setting of the new value, perhaps with a short `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame.`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you please write he how i should do it?highly appreciated

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol $('div').removeClass('bar'),should i do this?